# FIND_IN_SET is getting wrong results

Tags: mysql

First, I searched about the same problem but I didn't find an appropriate solution.

My problem is with the following code, it's returning wrong results:

```
SELECT FbID,FhID, 
       FbRef,
       FbDate, 
       (D.AccName) AS DName,
       FbQuan,
       CONCAT(CategoryName,'-',ProductName) AS ProdName,
       (C.AccName) AS CusName,
       FhPurPrice,FbSalePrice,
       (R.AccName) AS ResoName,
       Curr1.CurrencyName,
       Curr2.CurrencyName,
       Plc1.PlaceName AS FhResoPlaceName,
       Plc2.PlaceName AS FbCusPlaceName,
       'linked' AS xLinkStatus,
       1 AS xStatus 
FROM tblfatora2 F2 
INNER JOIN tblfatora1 F1 ON F1.FhRef = F2.FhRef
INNER JOIN tblproducts P ON P.ProductID = F1.FhProduct
INNER JOIN tblcategories CT ON CT.CategoryID = P.ProductCategory
INNER JOIN tblaccounts R ON R.AccID = F1.FhReso
INNER JOIN tblaccounts C ON C.AccID = F2.FbCus
INNER JOIN tblaccounts D ON D.AccID = F1.FhDriver
INNER JOIN tblcurrencies Curr1 ON C.AccCurrID = Curr1.CurrencyID
INNER JOIN tblcurrencies Curr2 ON R.AccCurrID = Curr2.CurrencyID
LEFT JOIN tblplaces Plc1 ON F1.FhResoPlace = Plc1.PlaceID
LEFT JOIN tblplaces Plc2 ON F2.FbCusPlace = Plc2.PlaceID
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`FhID`, '18313,18314')
ORDER BY FbDate, FbID
```

the results that it gives me are: enter image description here

note: I use FIND_IN_SET here because I can't use (IN) where I use that SQL statement in a procedure inside vb.net code:

```
 Public Sub MySql_GetLinked()
        xDtAll = New DataTable()

        Dim xPar(0) As MySqlParameter
        xPar(0) = New MySqlParameter("@FhID", MySqlDbType.String) With {
                                            .Value = LinkedFatora}

        xClsMySql.GetData(xSqlLinked, xDtAll, xPar)
    End Sub
```

So I fill the variable (LinkedFatora) by loop and I use the same SQL statement but I replace (WHERE FIND_IN_SET('FhID', '18313,18314')) with (WHERE FIND_IN_SET('FhID', @FhID)).

I looked for the error's reason but couldn't catch it.

Comment: Check the doc on [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Then, maybe, try `FIND_IN_SET(whatever) IS NOT NULL` in your `WHERE` clause. And, for troubleshooting try using a much simpler query.

Comment: Your use of `FIND_IN_SET()` instead of `IN()` makes your query non-sargable. You really should refactor your code so that you can pass the ids as multiple params to `IN()`.

Comment: @nnichols as I mentioned I can't use (IN) because with the parameters (IN) should be string like that ( '1,2,3' ) so how I can use (IN) with string parameters

Comment: When you build up the placeholders for the IN clause you just need to know how many values are being passed - `FhID IN (?, ?)`.

Comment: If you cannot use WHERE IN (I doubt that this is true, but nevertheless) then use `WHERE FhID = 18313 OR FhID = 18314`.

Comment: If you can't fix it properly, a dirty workaround might be to use `FhID IN (@In1, @In2, @In3, @In4, @In5)` and then when binding the values you can just pass null for any that you do not need, resulting in `FhID IN (18313, 18314, null, null, null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it's changing (WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`FhID`, '18313,18314')) to (WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`FbID`, '18313,18314')):

```
SELECT FbID,FhID, 
       FbRef,
       FbDate, 
       (D.AccName) AS DName,
       FbQuan,
       CONCAT(CategoryName,'-',ProductName) AS ProdName,
       (C.AccName) AS CusName,
       FhPurPrice,FbSalePrice,
       (R.AccName) AS ResoName,
       Curr1.CurrencyName,
       Curr2.CurrencyName,
       Plc1.PlaceName AS FhResoPlaceName,
       Plc2.PlaceName AS FbCusPlaceName,
       'linked' AS xLinkStatus,
       1 AS xStatus 
FROM tblfatora2 F2 
INNER JOIN tblfatora1 F1 ON F1.FhRef = F2.FhRef
INNER JOIN tblproducts P ON P.ProductID = F1.FhProduct
INNER JOIN tblcategories CT ON CT.CategoryID = P.ProductCategory
INNER JOIN tblaccounts R ON R.AccID = F1.FhReso
INNER JOIN tblaccounts C ON C.AccID = F2.FbCus
INNER JOIN tblaccounts D ON D.AccID = F1.FhDriver
INNER JOIN tblcurrencies Curr1 ON C.AccCurrID = Curr1.CurrencyID
INNER JOIN tblcurrencies Curr2 ON R.AccCurrID = Curr2.CurrencyID
LEFT JOIN tblplaces Plc1 ON F1.FhResoPlace = Plc1.PlaceID
LEFT JOIN tblplaces Plc2 ON F2.FbCusPlace = Plc2.PlaceID
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`FbID`, '18313,18314')
ORDER BY FbDate, FbID
```